# Python; NameError: name 'handsum' is not defined

Tags: python, blackjack

I am coding a basic BlackJack game, and I challenged myself to make as many functions as possible, so that the code looks like this:

```
funcA()
funcB()
funcC()
```

As opposed to:

```
funcA()
print("this")
print("that")
funcB()
```

Here is where my problem is in my code:

```
def playerTurn():
    global handSum
    global cardOne
    global cardTwo
    global dealerSum
    global upCard
    global downCard
    global bet
    global newCard
    global dealerNewCard
    str(handsum)
    str(cardOne)
    str(cardTwo)
    str(upCard)
    str(money)
    print("You are lying at", handSum, "with a", cardOne, 'and a', cardTwo 

    + '.', "The Dealer has a", upCard, "facing up. You have $" + money + '.')
    int(handsum)
    int(cardOne)
    str(cardTwo)
    str(upCard)
    str(money)
    sleep(1.3)
    bet=int(input('How much would you like to bet? '))
    sleep(1.3)
    money-=bet
    print("Your bet is $%s." %bet)
    sleep(2.5)
    playerInput=input(str(print('''Would you like to:
    Hit (H)
    Stand (S)
    Double (D)
    Stick (SP)
    Enter Letter for Answer: '''))).upper
    sleep(1)
    while True:
        Hit()
        Stick()
        Double()
        Quit()
```

And here's the error I get once my code reaches this function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Python\Games\Python 3.X\BlackJack\BlackJack.py", 

line 20, in <module>
    Start()

  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Python\Games\Python 3.X\BlackJack\BlackJack.py", 

line 16, in Start
    Intro()

  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Python\Games\Python 

  3.X\BlackJack\PlayerTurns.py", line 242, in Intro
    playerTurn()

  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Python\Games\Python 

  3.X\BlackJack\PlayerTurns.py", line 188, in playerTurn
    str(handsum)

NameError: name 'handsum' is not defined
```

I am using multiple python files (2) for this game.

Comment: It doesn't look like it but everything is properly Indented.

Comment: `handsum` and `handSum` is a different variables.

Comment: Way **too many `global`s**.

Comment: And all those standalone `str()` and `int()` calls do **exactly nothing**.

Comment: Whatever you think saying `str(cardOne)` does, I'm pretty sure it doesn't do that. What it does is this: try to convert cardOne to a string, raise an error if it can't, and then ignore the converted value if it can.

Comment: It's not a good practice to use **global** and you are using them way too many times.

Answer (score 1):

In python, a line like

```
str(handsum)
```

means that you are calling the function `str` with the argument `handsum`, and then disgarding the result. You do not, at this point in the function, have a variable called `handsum` in scope. Due to your `global handSum` line (note the capital **S** in sum) you *do* have a similarly named, but different variable in scope. You probably meant to refer to this variable, but python is case-sensitive.

However, I don't know why you want to call `str` on a variable and throw away the return value. This will not declare `handSum` (you don't need to declare python variables, they are created on assignment, and you can bring them into scope with the `global` keyword) nor will it convert `handSum` (if you changed the capitalisation) into a string (you would need to use the return value of `str(handSum)` for that), or indeed, do anything at all.

Also, you don't want to use `global`s for all those variables. Pass them as arguments to the function, or wrap them into an object. This helps compartmentalise problems in the future.